# I need inlt a sample code to download a pdf file from url on my android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, fileopener2

How can I download PDF file from URL with ionic angular capacitor. please some sapmle code. I need to download a Pdf file on My android.
I tried to used File-opener to download PDF file on android but IT Couldn't resulved .
please help ?